# How to calculate Expected Value when outcomes are infinte?

Tags: expected-value, infinity

Hello i am relatively new to statistics and I struggle with a problem like this:

*Assuming the chance of a fatal accident is 0.01 each day  given that it hasn't yet happened.
When can you expect it to happen, assuming that the fatal accident can only happen once?*

As far as I can understand I cannot use Expected Value because the possible outcomes are infinite.

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: The phrasing of this problem is poor.  I assume what is meant is instead *Assuming the chance of a fatal accident is 0.01 each day* **given that it hasn't yet happened**... For this, it is a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) and the usual results apply.

Comment: Yes you are right! I will add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value can, in fact, be expressed as an infinite sum. If we let $T$ be the number of days until the accident occurs, and assume independence, we have \begin{align*}
\mathbb P(T=1)&= 0.01\\
\mathbb P(T=2)&=(1-0.01)(0.01)\\
\mathbb P(T=3)&= (1-0.01)^2(0.01)\\
\mathbb P(T=t)&= (1-0.01)^{t-1}(0.01)
\end{align*}
In other words $T$ follows a geometric distribution with parameter $0.01$, and support $\{1,2,\cdots\}$. The expected value can be found with the following infinite sum: \begin{align*}
\mathbb E(T)&= \sum_{t=1}^\infty t\,\mathbb P(T=t)=\sum_{t=1}^\infty t(0.99)^{t-1}(0.01)=\cdots =\frac{1}{0.01}=100
\end{align*}